# Text to the right and center vertical of another textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have two textView. One - text holder, second - count holder. When text holder is one width, [all seems correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGmP.png) But when text is two and more strings, my amount textview leaves screen. ([look screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPGjd.png)). I've tried relative and constrains, but all doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_general_16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_general"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_general"
        tools:text="Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small_8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/redorange"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_general"
        tools:text="50"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:text="50"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` attribute.

Set Weight of TextViews according to your need.

Try below Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_general_16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_general_16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_general"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_general"
        android:text="Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_general_16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testAmount"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small_8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/redorange"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_general"
        android:text="50"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small_8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope its Work for you.